# Escape semi colon in "CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA" statement

Tags: java, oracle, navicat

I'm trying to execute the following statement in Navicat,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED util
AS
import java.io.IOException;

public class Util
{
    public static String exec(String cmd) throws IOException
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        return "";
    }
}
```

But since `;` is treated as a delimiter in SQL query, the query became "incomplete" and results in an error:

[image]

So how can I execute this statement in Navicat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the command as a string and dynamically execute it with an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```SQL
begin
    execute immediate
    '
        CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED util
        AS
        import java.io.IOException;

        public class Util
        {
            public static String exec(String cmd) throws IOException
            {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                return "";
            }
        }
    ';
end;
/
```

Not many Oracle IDEs understand the Java syntax, but I would assume that almost all of them can work with PL/SQL blocks.